# Being Detected Using Selenium With Reset Password TikTok (python)

Tags: python, selenium, automation

My goal is to reset the password of my tiktok accounts every x days, my though process started with how can i reset the password of my tiktok account using the email. I wrote a code that take the email I have from a txt file full of all my accounts emails. The problem is every time I try to reset my account it shows " You are trying to use our service too frequently. This only happens when i am on a selenium browser, it works fine on normal browsers. I tried playing with the UserAgents, tried the $csh removal from the chrome driver but no solution

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

#iniatialization of the driver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument(f'user-agent=Googlebot')


browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
#puts all the links into a username
with open('list.txt', 'r') as f:
    emails = [line.strip() for line in f]


for email in emails:
    browser.get('https://www.tiktok.com/login/email/forget-password')
    time.sleep(2)
    inputEmail= browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[1]/form/div[2]/div/input')
    inputEmail.send_keys(str(email))
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[1]/form/div[3]/button').click()
    time.sleep(1)
    #didnt continue the code because this was not working
```

what could be a possible solution?

Comment: Did you try real user-agent instead of Googlebot? Like: `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 8172.45.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.64 Safari/537.36`

Comment: @GooDeeJAY yes i did, still no result

Comment: if you have `a txt file full of all my accounts emails.` then it may see you too often and maybe you should slow down (a lot slow down) or use proxy servers.

Comment: its not that, @furas it doesnt even let you do 1 email on a selenium browser but works fine on a normal browser

Comment: could you overcome it ?